# What does each element of printf's #%ld!\n mean?

Tags: c++, c, variables, syntax

```
 void* PrintHello(void *threadid)
 {
      long tid;
      tid =(long)threadid;
      printf("Hello World! It's me, thread #%ld!\n",tid);
      pthread_exit(NULL);
 }
```

I'm wondering what each element of the variable declaration stands for and if there is an easier way (more readable/analogous) to just printf?

# =

% =

ld = Long int

! = not?

\n = new line

Also, the pointers seem to be written in two different ways on our slides.

There is:

```
 void* function_name(void* args)
```

And there is:

```
 void* function_name(void *args)
```

What is the significance of the asterisk location?  Which looks to be correct in this example?

Comment: Except for the one you listed, they're just characters.

Comment: @Dai: not true.  The `%` is present (`%ld`).

Comment: `%ld` refers to the `tid` variable, `#` and `!` are just regular characters.

Comment: The spaces are ignored `void* args`, `void *args`, `void * args` and `void*args` all mean the same.

Comment: Your `PrintHello` function invokes undefined behavior since you failed to return a `void *`.

Comment: `%ld` is a format specifier for printing a `long int` as a decimal number, `\n` is an escape sequence for a newline, and everything else prints just as it appears in the format string.

Comment: Are you ever gonna select a good answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you would also be interested to see the analogous C++ statement?

Also, for some of you, the C++ version will explain what the printf format info does.

---

- std::printf by default directs the output to stdout.  C++ uses std::cout
- '#' and '!' are just characters (in both forms)

So, in C++:

```
std::cout << '#' << tid << "!\n";
```

However, I would probably use:

```
std::cout << '#' << tid << '!' << std::endl;
```

---

Notes:

- Did you notice there is no %ld?  The compiler already knows the type of tid (i.e. long int), so you need not explain it a second time to std::cout like you would have to with std::printf.
- As an additional benefit, when someone changes the tid type to int32_t (or perhaps int64_t, or static_cast to something smaller), the cout line is un-affected.  Quick, what is XX of %XXd for a "long long unsigned int"?  How about we never look that up again.

---

> What is the significance of the asterisk location? Which looks to be
>   correct in this example?

Both forms are 'correct'.  I prefer the '* ' form, probably because of my background (with little 'c' exposure).

Answer (score 4):

When printing something with a variable, you require `%` to declare this is the spot where the `var` input is gonna be. # is just a regular character. `ld` just represents the type of var you are inputting. In this case, `long`. `!` means nothing as well, it's just a regular character. Also, when printing a `var`, the only thing that matters (in this case) is the thing between the `%` and the variable type which is `ld` in this case. `\n` just means new line as you stated before.

The asterisks location doesn't change anything. Both of them are correct. The reason for the asterisks is just to tell you it's a pointer

Answer (score 2):

Read your compiler's documentation for `printf()`.  Or online documentation, like [this one](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), or [this one](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/?kw=printf).  Documentation will explain to you exactly what the various parameters and placeholders are.

In your example, `#` and `!` don't mean anything.  They are outside of any format specifier, so they are just literal character data like the majority of your format string content is.  Only specifiers preceded by `%` have any special meaning.

The `%` character is an escape character that tells `printf()` to process the following `ld` specifier. `printf()` will replace `%ld` with the value of the `tid` variable in the formatted string.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a particular keyword of C Language. 
let me explain by breaking it up.

```
#%ld!\n
```

Equals to

```
#   : Hash character to show count/numbers 
%ld : Specifier referencing a long integer that you want to show.
!   : Simple exclamatory character.
\n  : New line
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated already by others, `%ld` in format string `"Hello World! It's me, thread #%ld!\n"` defines the place where a variable of type `long` will be placed. `#` and `!` are ordinary characters, and `\n` stands for a new line (special character backslash gives the subsequent character a special meaning).

But there is another issue in your code when you assign `long tid =(long)threadid` while having `threadid` being of type `void*`, i.e. a pointer to some unspecific type. Actually, if you know that `threadid` will point to a long, you should write `long tid = *((long*)threadid)` in order to dereference the pointer and interpret it as particular type `long`; otherwise, you would assign the pointer value (i.e. some memory address).